# List numeric files which are higher than particular number

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I have list of files in directory,ending with numeric. As below:

```
play_football_3
play_football_4
play_football_5
play_football_15
play_football_59
```

I'm able to extract the last numeric digit of above files. as

```
echo "play_football_5" | cut -f3 -d"_"
```

Now Here i'm trying to list all files which have higher version then play_football_5.

Expected Output:

```
play_football_15
play_football_59
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
printf "%s\n" play_football_* | awk -F_ '$3>5'
```

`printf` will list all files in the current directory start with `play_football_` and `awk`  filters the files with the number greater than 5

Answer (score 3):

If you have `bash` 2.02-alpha1, or newer, you can turn on *"extended globbing*" and look for files starting `play_football_` and not ending with the digits 0-5 like this:

```
shopt -s extglob

ls play_football_!([0-5])
```

[Here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) is a reference to start learning more about it.

Comment: `extglob` was added in Bash 2.02-alpha1.  See [Bash changes [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges).

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
awk -F'_' '$3 > 5'
```

See the [online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/nDWGDJ)

With `-F'_'`, you set the delimiter to an underscore and with `'$3 > 5'`, only those lines (records) are printed where the third field is greater than `5`.

Comment: Wouldn't `$NF` be a bit better? :)

Comment: @mickp I think numbers, so `$3` appeals to me more than `$NF` :)

Comment: Hm, I thought `$NF` would be more universal for filenames such as `play_football_foo_15` :)

Comment: @mickp There is no `play_football_foo_15` in the example data. The use of `cut -f3 -d"_"` in OP implies `play_football_foo_15` like values are not expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can also keep your original idea doing something like this:

```
for file in $(ls | cut -d_ -f3)
do
  if [[ "$file" -gt 5 ]]
  then
    echo "play_football_$file"
  fi
done
```

If you do that while in the directory that has your files you will get:

```
play_football_15
play_football_59
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl one-liner

```
> ll
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxxxx devlgrp 0 Oct 30 14:41 play_football_5
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxxxx devlgrp 0 Oct 30 14:41 play_football_4
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxxxx devlgrp 0 Oct 30 14:41 play_football_3
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxxxx devlgrp 0 Oct 30 14:41 play_football_15
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxxxx devlgrp 0 Oct 30 14:41 play_football_59
> perl -ne ' BEGIN { @files=glob("play*");foreach(@files){ ($file=$_)=~s/.*_(\d+)/\1/g; print "$_\n" if $file > 5 } exit }'
play_football_15
play_football_59
>
```